# Adding a table of contents to PDF with R plots

Tags: r, pdf

I'm creating a larger number of plots in R and save them as PDF (using grDevices / pdf). Is there an easy way to add a (meta-data) table of contents to the PDF as it is created?

I don't mean to add a separate page, but a TOC that PDF viewers like Preview.app display in the sidebar to make navigation easier.)

Example of such a TOC:

[image: Example table of contents]

Comment: I think it would be a very interesting and useful idea to have something like this in a package which extends the pdf device - but I have no idea if this would be simple to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I know is with LaTeX, but you don't necessarily need Sweave; perhaps you could just generate the LaTeX file directly with your RPython code.  If you've got two pictures which are 6x6 (the default size) named `tmp-001.pdf` and `tmp-002.pdf`, this is how you'd make a section called Section A with two subsections for the two pictures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in, paperheight=6in, margin=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent 0pt
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Section A}{anchorname_aa}

\pdfbookmark[2]{plot aa}{anchorname_aa}
\includegraphics{tmp-001.pdf}

\newpage
\pdfbookmark[2]{plot bb}{anchorname_bb}
\includegraphics{tmp-002.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Assume you have one Rplots.pdf with 8 pages. So just do `\includegraphics[page=3]{Rplots.pdf}`, I think.

Comment: Why your graphics are not inside figure environment? - - What is your execution engine? - - I cannot run your code in my system with pdflatex.

Comment: Yes, [page=X] works. I don't have them in a figure environment because we don't want the extra stuff that adds, we simply want the figures on the pages as is. I reran the document on my system and all is still well. What errors do you get?

Comment: Ok, I got it. My mistakes were then in the Figure class. - - This is my code without the figure class http://paste.ubuntu.com/23421878/ where I cannot adjust Rplot images into your example in Beamer.

Comment: You're obviously trying to do something different. Why use the beamer class at all? I recommend starting a new question.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a first page using the names of your objects or plots as the arguments to text in columns.

```
plot(1:10,1:10, type="n", main ="Index", axes=FALSE,frame.plot=FALSE,xlab="")

text(1,10, "plot")
text(3,10, "page")
text(5,1:10, rev(1:10+1))
text(2,1:10, rev(letters[1:10]))
```

[image: Base graphics version]

I cannot think of a way to generate a navigable TOC, but this option may be more pleasing and easier to integrate with Beamer-type displays. The Hmisc package function latex provides an interface to the Latex longtable package. My Latex-fu is weak but if yours is stronger, you could also divert the dvi code that is created for integration within other applications. I get an intermediate dvi file put in a temporary directory which then opens my dvi viewer and allows saving as pdf:

```
require(Hmisc)
?latex  # you will probably want to review this
latex(Plot_list<-data.frame(Plots=letters[1:10], Pages=2:11))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi DWin, thanks for your answer. I didn't mean, however, a separate page (unless I can click there to navigate). I have updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. I think you have to use sweave for that.

Comment: hmm... that's too bad. To make matters even worse, I use RPython and some loops to generate the plots. But perhaps I can add a page in the end with some links, I'll check this.